# What's the easiest way to convert ogg to webm on Node without ffmpeg?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, webm, arraybuffer, ogg

I'm working on a Telegram bot that can receive voice messages and then let OpenAI's Whisper transcribe them and then respond using OpenAI's chat completions API.

Anyway, Whisper does accept a `webm` file as an input, but not an `ogg` file. Even though ironically, from what I've read, a `webm` container can contain a pure `ogg` file as its soundtrack.

I can't use `ffmpeg`, because I'm deploying this as a serverless function (on Vercel for now) and I have no guarantee that `ffmpeg` will be installed there. But I was thinking, since `webm` is simply a container file which can contain the raw `ogg` `opus` codec as the soundtrack, wouldn't it be possible to just take the binary audio data that I can get from Telegram, using `const audioData = await response.arrayBuffer()`, and just add some bytes to the beginning and end of it that represent the `webm` container?

If yes, then can someone please tell me which bytes I'd need to add exactly?

Comment: Ogg is a container, just like WebM is a container.  I assume your audio is actually encoded with Opus, and you want to demux it from the Ogg, and then mux into WebM.  There's a lot of code to do this correctly, and it isn't worth your time to re-implement.  If you really must do this in plain JavaScript, you could always compile the necessary modules via Emscripten.  Realistically, you should pick a different host that is more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: If your target is serverless, maybe consider WebAssembly. [It is supported in Node.js](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/nodejs-with-webassembly/), meaning you can compile ffmpeg without a server back-end.

Comment: @aggregate1166877, my target is a docker container that runs on Google Cloud Run when deployed. And I don't need to compile ffmpeg, because the binaries are already included in the docker image. On my macbook, when I run the docker container, the conversion is very fast, often less than a second. But on Google Cloud Run, the conversion is extremely slow. Probably because I'm using the cheapest option which gives me a super slow CPU. But I prefer not to go for a higher-tier on Google Cloud Run, because my app doesn't generate enough income to justify paying more for the deployment.